# TO_Duration function from Ada.Real_time is not working

Tags: ada

I am working with the time difference calculation using the function `To_Duration`; but it is producing errors, as `To_Duration` is not in region of `Real_Time`. Pplease find the code snippet as below and Error shown below:

```
function Since_Start(Start_time: in Ada.Real_Time.Time; 
                     End_time: in Ada.Real_Time.Time) return String is
begin
    return Duration'Image(Ada.Real_Time.To_Duration(End_time - Start_time));
end Since_Start;
```

Error is as below:

> `To_Duration` was not found in the region of `Real_Time`, Ignored future references.

Please let me know if any idea why this is not working. If I put the same code on online tools it is working fine.

Comment: Which compiler version are you using? Which runtime system? Look at the RTS source files ... `a-reatim.ads` (for Gnat) which should declare `To_Duration`.  If I do that I see one that takes a `Time_Span`. And an `-` operator that returns a `Time-Span`, so that should work. Are you using a stripped down RTS for a small embedded system like the AVR or MSP430?

Comment: Hi I am using the Aonix Object Ada Teal-Time Raven IDE.

Comment: Then perhaps you can get support from your compiler vendor since it appears that they have omitted this functionality.

Comment: That compiler has been re-sold twice ... Aonix -> Atego -> PTC. See http://www.ptc.com/developer-tools/objectada for information and hopefully support. If they cannot provide support for the version you have, you may be able to use a different RTS or even add that functionality to the RTS you have.

Comment: Is the "-" operator visible? Try adding `use type Ada.Real_Time.Time;` in the declaration block

Comment: Indeed, another compiler reports that operator `"-"` (of type `Time`) is not visible. Guessing from what I have seen in similar cases, when the compiler starts looking for `To_Duration` of an argument of unknown type—since `"-"` is anavailable, this lack of precise information may confuse the compiler's type based search—it will not find a suitable `To_Duration` in any region, and not in `Ada.Real_Time` in particular. (Assuming "region" means "declarative region").

Comment: Come to think, egilhh, OP says the same code worked in another compiler (whatever "online tools" means) so `"-"` should be visible

Comment: @SimonWright: maybe [_compile ada online_](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_ada_online.php)?